Zimbra API, uploading file produces server error on upload
I have an application that creates email messages in Zimbra. It does this by posting a MIME file, taking the resulting MimeId, then calling AddMsgRequest, specifying the MimeId that was received.
This works just fine on my server and that of all customers who have used the software, except for one. In this case, AddMsgRequest returns with http error 500. Looking at the server log, the specific error code is "mail.NO_SUCH_UPLOAD". Looking a few lines back in the log, I can see that after the upload I get this error:
FileUploadServlet - mismatched accountId for upload: Upload: { accountId=5061fd80-aca6-4044-ab8c-9b345fede45b, time=Thu Oct 10 16:22:23 BDT 2024, size=1153, uploadId=f44bd411-ee96-4bee-a657-b28efd73e5ac:dcb54686-b6ae-44c4-8841-a1b964a0b759, name=mime.bin, path=null }; expected: accountId=b1f59281-ce8d-4a9b-8f21-d51b487d8475, uploadId=f44bd411-ee96-4bee-a657-b28efd73e5ac:dcb54686-b6ae-44c4-8841-a1b964a0b759

The UploadId referenced in that line is the same MimeId that I receive after the post (which returns http 200). I have no idea what "accountId" is.  That is not anything that is specified anywhere in my code.
Can anyone explain what's going on here?
